# Erro ao acessar alteração de Estado que possui um País

Tags: sql, delphi, mvc, firebird

Eu tenho um cadastro de estado, que possui um País. Ele cadastra normal, só que ocorre erro ao acessar a alteração do estado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se está correto, mas pelo que eu entendi, algo do país está vindo vazio. Como que eu corrijo isso. Eu não estou conseguindo.

A arquitetura que estou utilizando é a MVC. e estou programando em Delphi.

No meu sistema, todos os cadastros que possuem outros cadastros, ocorre esse erro.
Tanto que no cadastro de cidade, eu nem consigo adicionar o estado porque ocorre esse mesmo erro, mas falando do estado.

DAO ESTADOS:

```
function daoEstados.carregar(pObj: TObject): string;
var mEstado : Estados; mPais : Paises;
begin
  mEstado:= Estados( pObj );
  mPais:= mEstado.getoPais;

  mEstado.setCodigo( aDM.QEstados.FieldByName('CODESTADO').Value );
  mEstado.setEstado( aDM.QEstados.FieldByName('ESTADO').AsString );
  mEstado.setUF( aDM.QEstados.FieldByName('UF').AsString );

  mPais.setCodigo( aDM.QEstados.FieldByName('CODPAIS').Value );
  mPais.setPais( aDM.QPaises.FieldByName('PAIS').AsString );
  mPais.setDDI( aDM.QPaises.FieldByName('DDI').AsString );
  mPais.setSigla( aDM.QPaises.FieldByName('SIGLA').AsString );

  mEstado.setDataCad( aDM.QEstados.FieldByName('DATACAD').AsDateTime );
end;
```

Na CONTROLLER ESTADOS:

```
function ctrlEstados.carregar(pObj: TObject): string;
var mPais : Paises; AFilter: TFilterSearch; tipoConsulta : TTipoConsulta;
begin
  aDaoEstados.carregar( pObj );

  mPais:= Estados( pObj ).getoPais;
  aCtrlPaises.pesquisar(AFilter, IntToStr(mPais.getCodigo));
  aCtrlPaises.carregar( oEstado.getoPais );
end;
```

Ela chama o método pesquisa da *controller* país, que chama da *dao*:

```
msql:= '';

case AFilter.TipoConsulta of

 TpCCodigo:
 begin
   msql:= 'SELECT * FROM PAISES WHERE CODPAIS =' + IntToStr( 
   AFilter.Codigo );
 end;

 TpCParam:
 begin
   msql:= ( 'SELECT * FROM PAISES WHERE PAIS LIKE ' + QuotedStr( 
 '%' + AFilter.Parametro + '%' ) );
 end;

 TpCDDI:
 begin
   msql:= ( 'SELECT * FROM PAISES WHERE DDI LIKE ' + QuotedStr( 
 '%' + AFilter.DDI + '%' ) );
 end;

 TpCMoeda:
 begin
   msql:= ( 'SELECT * FROM PAISES WHERE MOEDA LIKE ' + QuotedStr( 
  '%' + AFilter.Moeda + '%' ) );
 end;

 TpCTODOS:
 begin
   msql:= 'SELECT * FROM PAISES ORDER BY CODPAIS';
 end;

end;

aDM.QPaises.Active:= false;
aDM.QPaises.SQL.Text:=msql;
aDM.QPaises.Open;
result:= '';
```

Nesse método pesquisar, fiz um *case* para saber o tipo de filtro que está selecionado para consulta.

Só que quando chega nessa parte:

```
aDM.QPaises.Open;
```

É que ocorre o erro.

Comment: Qual código que ao ser executado gera esse erro?

Comment: Ocorre erro na Dao País. AQUI
    aDM.QPaises.Active:= false;
    aDM.QPaises.SQL.Text:=msql;
    aDM.QPaises.Open; -> AQUI
    result:= '';
Na Controller Estado tem esse método: 
function ctrlEstados.carregar(pObj: TObject): string;
var mPais : Paises; AFilter: TFilterSearch; tipoConsulta : TTipoConsulta;
begin
  aDaoEstados.carregar( pObj );
  mPais:= Estados( pObj ).getoPais;
  aCtrlPaises.pesquisar(AFilter, IntToStr(mPais.getCodigo));
  aCtrlPaises.carregar( oEstado.getoPais );
end;
Ele acessa o método pesquisar da controller, que nele vai chamar a pesquisa da DAO do País.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Não sei se está correto, mas pelo que eu entendi, algo do país está
> vindo vazio. Como que eu corrijo isso. Eu não estou conseguindo.

A mensagem de erro apresentada:

> Comand [QPaises] text must be not empty

Traduzindo a mensagem de erro apresentada, temos:

> O texto do comando de QPaises não deve estar vazio.

**O Problema:**
O problema é que a variável `msql` não está recebendo um novo valor, essa variável **inicia vazia** e caso não satisfaça a condição `case AFilter.TipoConsulta of`, não receberá uma novo valor, permanecendo vazia.

**Uma possível correção:**
Para corrigir, na `controller país` inicie a variável de forma genérica:
substitua o trecho:

```
msql = '';
```

por

```
msql = 'SELECT * FROM PAISES';
```

Dessa forma, se alguma condição não satisfizer o `case`, você terá uma consulta padrão a ser executada.

```
aDM.QPaises.Active:= false;
aDM.QPaises.SQL.Text:=msql;
aDM.QPaises.Open;
```

Como não estava fazendo nenhuma verificação antes de atribuir o `msql`, tudo indica que está sendo atribuído um valor vazio e o erro está sendo gerado.

**Outra correção possível:**

```
aDM.QPaises.Active:= false;
if msql <> '' Then
   aDM.QPaises.SQL.Text:=msql
else
   aDM.QPaises.SQL.Text:= 'SELECT * FROM PAISES';  //Sua consulta padrão
aDM.QPaises.Open;
```

Comment: Muito obrigada. Deu certo. Nossa que alívio kkkkkk